# Get only the keys of a plist

Tags: common-lisp

I do the following code to retrieve only the keys of a plist:

```
(loop :for (key nil) :on config :by #'cddr
      :collect key))
```

Running this produces:

```
CONFIG-TEST> (loop :for (key nil) :on '(:foo 1 :bar 2) :by #'cddr
                   :collect key)
(:FOO :BAR)
```

Is there a more 'functional' way to do this than using LOOP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the SERIES package, `scan-plist` returns two series, one for the keys, the other for values:

```
(scan-plist '(:a 3 :b 2))
=> #Z(:A :B)
   #Z(3 2)
```

You can rely on this to collect the first series as a list:

```
(collect 'list (scan-plist '(:a 3 :b 2)))
```

More generally, you may want to process the values in some way, so you would use `mapping`. For example, here is a `plist-alist` made with SERIES:

```
(defun plist-alist (plist)
  (collect 'list
    (mapping (((k v) (scan-plist plist))) (cons k v))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Not really...

```
CL-USER 35 > (let ((? nil))
               (mapcon (lambda (l)
                         (when (setf ? (not ?))
                           (list (first l))))
                       '(:foo 1 :bar 2)))
(:FOO :BAR)
```

or maybe:

```
(defun mapncar (fn list &key (start 0) (n 1))
  (loop for l = (nthcdr start list) then (nthcdr n l)
        while l
        collect (funcall fn (first l))))

CL-USER 61 > (mapncar #'identity '(a 1 b 2 c 3) :n 2)
(A B C)

CL-USER 62 > (mapncar #'identity '(a 1 b 2 c 3) :start 1 :n 2)
(1 2 3)
```

Comment: Pfieww. I still have to sort out what `mapcon` does. :)

Comment: @manfred: MAPCON concatenates the lambda function result lists. This allows an empty list as a return value from a function to have the effect of no element in the result list. With MAPCAR a NIL result from the function would mean a NIL element in the MAPCAR result list.

Answer (score 3):

What stylistic direction would `do` take us?

```
CL-USER> (do ((result (list) (cons (car plist) result))
              (plist '(:foo 1 :bar 2) (cddr plist)))
             ((null plist) (reverse result)))
(:FOO :BAR)
```

By the way, I'd write the loop with less syntax, will this bite me?

```
CL-USER> (loop for key in '(:foo 1 :bar 2) by 'cddr
               collecting key)
(:FOO :BAR)
```

Comment: The last one looks more simple than what I have.

Comment: @Manfred The main difference is using for-as-in-list which does the job of picking the first element of the remaining list.

Answer (score 2):

With the **Serapeum** library, which I consider as a second must-have just after Alexandria: use `plist-keys` :)

```lisp
(serapeum:plist-keys '(:a 1 :b 2))
;; (:A :B)
```

https://github.com/ruricolist/serapeum/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#plist-keys-plist

Here's its implementation:

```lisp
(defun plist-keys (plist)
  "Return the keys of a plist."
  (collecting*
    (doplist (k v plist)
      (collect k))))
```

It also has `plist-values`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(ql:quickload :alexandria)

(mapcar #'car (alexandria:plist-alist '(:a 1 :b 2)))
;; => (:A :B)
```

To remove dependency of alexandria, define yourself `plist-alist`:

```
(defun plist-alist (l &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
        (t (plist-alist (cddr l) (cons (cons (car l) (cadr l)) acc)))))
```

However, dependency on `:alexandria` should not be counted as dependency.

#### directly

Actyally, one could change `plist-alist` definition to obtain only the keys:

```
(defun plist-keys (l &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
        (t (plist-keys (cddr l) (cons (car l) acc)))))
```

And likewise the values:

```
(defun plist-vals (l &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
        (t (plist-vals (cddr l) (cons (cadr l) acc)))))
```

Comment: From a 'functional' perspective I like this the most. Even though PLIST-ALIST function doesn't seem to be very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that none of the values are of type symbol, you could filter for symbols:

```
(remove-if-not #'symbolp '(:a 1 :b 2)) ;;=> (:A :B)
```

Much less efficient, but universersal:

- filter for `symbolp` and `getf`-ability
  (Only keys of a plist are `getf`-able from the plist, thus this is the check whether it is a key or not. However, a check, whether an element in a plist is `symbolp` is cheaper and removes most of the non-key values,
  thus saving time and cost).

```
(defun get-plist-keys (plist)
  (remove-if-not #'(lambda (x) (and (symbolp x) (getf plist x))) plist))

(get-plist-keys '(:a 1 :b 2 :c :d))
;; => (:A :B :C)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun plist-keys (plist)
  "Get just the keys of a plist."
  (loop for key in plist by #'cddr collecting key))

(defun plist-values (plist)
  "Get just the values of a plist."
  (loop for value in (rest plist) by #'cddr collecting value))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**